# group columns and get specific value in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

I have a file wherein I have to group columns 1,2 & 3, sum up column 7, get the count, and get column 4 and 5 having latest datetime (column 6).

FILE.txt

```
 AAA,BBB,CCC,OOO,PPP,20170117012006,12
 XXX,YYY,MMM,OOO,PPP,20170117012006,13
 AAA,BBB,CCC,III,TTT,20170117020006,14
 XXX,YYY,MMM,OOO,PPP,20170117022067,10
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 AAA,BBB,CCC,III,TTT,26,2
 XXX,YYY,MMM,OOO,PPP,23,2
```

I have a code here but only groups columns 1,2,3.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","}{arr[$1,$2,$3]+=$7 }{arr2[$1,$2,$3]++}END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i],arr2[i]}' FILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use additional arrays to hold the latest information for each group.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="," }
    {
        arr[$1,$2,$3]+=$6; 
        arr2[$1,$2,$3]++;
        if ($6 > latest[$1,$2,$3]) {
            latest[$1,$2,$3] = $6;
            latest_data[$1,$2,$3] = $4 OFS $5;
        }
    }
    END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i],arr2[i],latest_data[i]}' FILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '                     
{
    i=$1","$2","$3
    if (i in a) {
        split(a[i],r,",")
        $7+=r[4]                    
        c=r[5]+1                  
        if (r[1] > $6) { $4=r[2]; $5=r[3]; $6=r[1] }
    } else { c=1 }

    a[$1","$2","$3]=$6","$4","$5","$7","c

} END { for (i in a) { print i substr(a[i],15) }} 
' file

 AAA,BBB,CCC,III,TTT,26,2
 XXX,YYY,MMM,OOO,PPP,23,2
```

If you want columns 1,2 & 3 sorted, then use this instead

```
END { asorti(a,b); for (i in b) { print b[i] substr(a[b[i]],15) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

@User101: Try following, it will give you expected/requested output along with the same sequence of $1,$2,$3 same as per Input_file only.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{A[$1,$2,$3]=A[$1,$2,$3]?A[$1,$2,$3]+$7:$7;;B[$1,$2,$3]++;next} (($1,$2,$3) in A){$NF="";print $0 A[$1,$2,$3] "," B[$1,$2,$3];delete A[$1,$2,$3]}' OFS=, SUBSUP=,   Input_file  Input_file
```

making field separator as ",". FNR==NR will be TRUE when very first file will be read. creating array named A whose index is $1,$2,$3 and it will concatenate the value of $7 to it. Creating one more array named B whose index is also $1,$2,$3 for taking count of $1,$2,$3.

Then checking ($1,$2,$3) in A if first, second, third field are present in array A if yes then printing the current line(whose last field we have made it as NULL) along with array A's and array B's values as per request.

**EDIT:** Adding non-one liner form of solution too successfully now.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{
                 A[$1,$2,$3]=A[$1,$2,$3]?A[$1,$2,$3]+$7:$7;
                 B[$1,$2,$3]++;
                 next
                }
                (($1,$2,$3) in A){
                                        $NF="";
                                        print $0 A[$1,$2,$3] "," B[$1,$2,$3];
                                        delete A[$1,$2,$3]
                                 }
        ' OFS=, SUBSUP=,  Input_file  Input_file
```